# How can I deploy VM images from Container Registry using Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-container-registry

I can see that my VM images are available in Google Container Registry following execution of the  commands :

```
docker tag sutechnology/transcode eu.gcr.io/supereye/transcode

docker push eu.gcr.io/supereye/transcode

gcloud auth configure-docker docker push eu.gcr.io/supereye/transcode
```

Although I can see the images, I haven't been able to use this image while creating a new instance in Google Compute Engine. How can I use the image that I see in Container Registry while creating a new VM instance? Here below is my full config :

```
machine_type = "zones/europe-west2-b/machineTypes/n1-standard-1"
disk_type = "zones/europe-west2-b/diskTypes/pd-standard"

config = {
    'name': name,
    'machineType': machine_type,

    # Specify the boot disk and the image to use as a source.
    'disks': [
        {
            'boot': True,
            'autoDelete': True,
            'initializeParams': {
                'sourceImage': source_disk_image,
            }
        }
    ],

    # Specify a network interface with NAT to access the public
    # internet.
    'networkInterfaces': [{
        'network': 'global/networks/default',
        'accessConfigs': [
            {'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT', 'name': 'External NAT'}
        ]
    }],

    # Allow the instance to access cloud storage and logging.
    'serviceAccounts': [{
        'email': 'default',
        'scopes': [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'
        ]
    }],

    # Metadata is readable from the instance and allows you to
    # pass configuration from deployment scripts to instances.
    'metadata': {
        'items': [{
            # Startup script is automatically executed by the
            # instance upon startup.
            'key': 'startup-script',
            'value': startup_script,
            'VIDEOPATH': videopath
        }]
    }
}
```

And instance creation function below :

```
compute.instances().insert(
        project=project,
        zone=zone,
        body=config).execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Container Registry (GCR), is used for storing docker images, which is then used to create the containers **NOT** compute Engine machine.

For Compute Engine, either use the public Images or Custom Images Snapshots of existing machines.

> For Ref:- https://cloud.google.com/container-registry

Hope this helps